# In stores, how do I see the stats of the items that they have for sale?

Tags: pc, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

[image]

I wanted to see if the Daggers of Puncturing where better than the ones that I am wearing, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I hover the pointer over the item, nothing. I double click the item, no confirmation, just a direct purchase. What do I have to do?

Comment: I realize this question is about the PC version, Just in case anyone with the Xbox version stumbles across this question...   I have the option to "compare" an item against what I've got equipped by pressing the X button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can right-click on the item and select Compare

That's just a guess though. I have the Xbox version which allows you to hit X to compare items, and based on other screenshots I've seen of the game, any Xbox button commands can be found in the Context Menu of the item in the PC version

Comment: That is right! Thank you so much. I do feel a little stupid :p